# How to bind id in datalist form

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I have some datalist in razor page:

```
<form asp-page-handler="AddUser" method="post">
<input type="search" list="datalistusers" id="searchid" name="userName" placeholder="Введите имя.." />
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
     Добавить
</button>
     <datalist id="datalistusers">
     @foreach (var user in @Model.Course.UserCourses)
     {
         <option>@user.User.Name</option>
     }
</datalist>
</form>
```

When I sumbit form in method I get only username. How can i bind user id in this form?

Codebehind:

```
public IActionResult OnPostAddUser(string username,string userid)
{
    //some action
    //done
    return Page();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you only passed/ bind username from your form, that's why you're only getting username in the controller action. you've to bind userid also in your form. like bellow

```
     <form asp-page-handler="AddUser" method="post">
            <input type="search" list="datalistusers" id="searchid" name="userName" placeholder="Введите имя.." />
            <input type="text"  id="userid" name="userid" placeholder="Enter User Id" />
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                Добавить
            </button>
            <datalist id="datalistusers">
                @foreach (var user in @Model.Course.UserCourses)
                {
                    <option>@user.User.Name</option>
                }
            </datalist>
        </form>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but that's not what I need. I need to bind user id from datalist when i select some <option> in UI

Comment: from where you will get userid? from your model? And I guess your model is list type. Am I right?

Comment: model contains object 'Course', course have list of users. every user contains userid. Datalist is users from course. input searching by user name

Comment: So you want to send all userid / single one / first one / last one?

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

cshtml.cs:

```
private readonly MyDbContext _context;

public TestModel(MyDbContext context)
{
     _context = context;
}

public IList<User> Users { get; set; }
public async Task OnGetAsync()
{
     Users = await _context.User.ToListAsync();
}
public IActionResult OnPostAddUser(string username, string userid)
{
     //some action
     //done
     Users = _context.User.ToList();
     return Page();
}
```

cshtml:

```
<form asp-page-handler="AddUser" method="post">
        <input type="search" list="datalistusers" id="searchid" name="userName" placeholder="Введите имя.." />
        <input type="hidden" id="userid" name="userid" />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            Добавить
        </button>
        <datalist id="datalistusers">
            @foreach (var user in Model.Users)
            {
                <option>@user.Name</option>
            }
        </datalist>
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("#searchid").change(function() {
    var value = $("#searchid").val();
    var items = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model.Users))
    items.forEach(function (item) {
        console.log(item)
        if (value == item.name) 
        { 
            $("#userid").val(item.id)
        }
    })
});
</script>
```

Maybe this is what you want?

You can add another `input` and set it to `type="hidden"`, and then use JS to match the userid corresponding to the userName you selected.

Below is my test code:

```
<form asp-page-handler="AddUser" method="post">
        <input type="search" list="datalistusers" id="searchid" name="userName" placeholder="Введите имя.." />
        <input type="hidden" id="userid" name="userid" />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            Добавить
        </button>
        <datalist id="datalistusers">
                <option>TestName1</option>
                <option>TestName2</option>
                <option>TestName3</option>
        </datalist>
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("#searchid").change(function() {
    // Add loop over Model to match id
    if ($("#searchid").val() == "TestName1") 
    {
        $("#userid").val("1");
    } 
    else if ($("#searchid").value == "TestName2") 
    {
        $("#userid").val("2");
    } 
    else 
    {
        $("#userid").val("3");
    }
});
</script>
```

Test Result:
[image]

Comment: datalist get items from db, so this solution is not my choice, but thanks for answer

Comment: @sandman633 I know that,You can replace the JS part with a loop for your `Model.Course.UserCourses`.I'll update my answer to see if it's what you want.